# What's wrong with this code in Ruby on Rails and HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

My Ruby on Rails version is 4.2.3, this is a helper in application_helper.rb it suppose to print flash notifications in views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
def flash_message key, message, dismissible
    dismiss = dismissible ? " alert-dismissible" : ""
    content_tag :div, class: flash_class(key.to_sym) + dismiss do
                if dismissible
                    content_tag(:button, {type: "button", class: "close", "data-dismiss" => "alert", "aria-label" => "Close"}) do
                        content_tag :span, {"aria-hidden" => "true"} do
                            "&times"
                        end
                    end
                end

                content_tag :span, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"

                message
            end
end
```

On views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
- if flash.any?
            - flash.each do |key, message|
                    = flash_message key, message, true
```

It doesn't display all the content it only displays the first div with class and the message which is fine but I still need the close button if the flash message is dismissible and the span with glyphicon class.

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">message</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The incoming argument is `dismissible` but you're testing `dismissable`

Comment: Sorry @SteveTurczyn it's just a typo I fixed it but the issue still exists, for some reason content_tag is only working with div elements.

Comment: In your content_tag block, you need to concat all of the parts into one string. Right now only the `message` is returned. All other parts are simply ignored.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev it worked it only needs the .html_safe method so it doesn't print HTML code on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SergioTulentsev suggested the content_tag should be concatenated but for the helper function to parse HTML properly not literally the message variable should be followed by .html_safe method.

Thanks for everyone's help.